# Clustering In google Map in Android

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-layout

I implemented googleMap by following code. it works fine but do not cluster these markes. The coordinates are being gotten from database. My question is how can I cluster markers.
Here is code

```
map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
            .getMap();

        if (map!=null) {

            try {
                SQLiteDatabase db = openOrCreateDatabase("Swaponce",
                        MODE_PRIVATE, null);

                Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM cord", null);

                cursor.moveToFirst();

                //ConnUrl=new String[cursor.getCount()];

                int i=0;

                do {
                    double lng = Double.parseDouble(cursor.getString(cursor
                            .getColumnIndex("lng")));

                    double lang =Double.parseDouble(cursor.getString(cursor
                            .getColumnIndex("lat")));
                    try {
                        LatLng cord = new LatLng(lang, lng);
                        Marker hamburg = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(cord)
                                  .title("").snippet("")
                                  .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                                          .fromResource(R.drawable.mappeopleindicator)));   
                    }
                    catch(Exception e) {

                    }

                } while (cursor.moveToNext());

                cursor.close();
                db.close();
            } 
            catch (Exception e) {
                int i = 0;
            }

            map.setOnMarkerClickListener(new OnMarkerClickListener() {      
                @Override
                public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker arg0) {
                    int i=0;

                    //swapview();
                    i++;
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clustering is a way far thing that you have done, you are only adding simple markers, without cluster option.

Please refer [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/utility/marker-clustering)